# Ajax loading doesnt work when form validates

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im using a form to upload files to my server and I want to load a progress bar when the form validates. This is code I have with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#uploadform").submit(function(e){
        var valid_form = validateForm();

        if (valid_form){
            $("#pb").load("/php/progressbar.php");
        }
        return valid_form;
    });
});
```

The problem is I get this message after submit:

```
GET http://ftplink.wedo/php/progressbar.php undefined (undefined)
```

But the weird thing is that I tried inverting the condition of the IF and when the form doesnt validate, the ajax loading actually happens. What is going on??

Comment: What is returned/is happening with in the validateForm method?

Comment: The validateForm returns true if the forms are filled properly, and false if they are not validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell everything from your question. I would guess that the form submit is happening while there is an active ajax request. You should return false, then submit the form when ajax finishes loading the progress bar.

```
if (valid_form){
    $("#pb").load("/php/progressbar.php", function(){
        $("#uploadform").unbind('submit').submit(); // unbind so you are not recursive
    });
}
return false;
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thanks! You are my hero today! Still curious why it's not working "the normal way". I think it's not the first time I've encountered this issue... You said something about an "active ajax request". I indeed make more ajax calls as the form is being filled, but how does an ajax requests remains active? I thought once it's loaded, it's closed, isnt it?

Comment: Pls, accept this answer by clicking the tick at left side of it - you'll reward your hero with additional reputation ;)

Comment: Welcome. The reason is because ajax is happening asynchronously. So if you send an ajax request, them post the form - the document will try to unload, but the ajax has not finished yet. Please accept the solution if this answer was helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the answer :) so that means that POST wins over AJAX? Because there is a waiting time until the file has been uploaded and i thought that time my ajax call would be executed :(

Comment: Well as soon as the post begins the document is unloaded. It does not know how long it will take to finish the post, but the any active ajax requests are canceled at that time.

Comment: But if at the moment of the POST, the Ajax calls are cancelled, how can it be possible to make a upload progress bar?? Im trying to do this: http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/

Comment: That is using an iframe technique - a hidden iframe posts the file, while your current document shows the progress.

Comment: @Josiah Hi, care to take a peek at mine? The problem seems related although different, can't wrap my head around it :S